# Looping n-1 times instead of n times. WHY?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int n,m,i,k;
scanf("%d",&n);
char sr[101][101];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    gets(sr[i]);
}
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
{
    m = strlen(sr[k]);
    if(m>10)
    {
        printf("%c%d%c\n",sr[k][0],(m-2),sr[k][m-1]);
    }
    else
    {
        puts(sr[k]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

if I use **i < n** here it is taking n-1 inputs. but why?
strating from 0,1,2,3...(n-1) shoudn't it take n times inputs?
for example if give 4 it is taking 3 inputs not 4.

Comment: Please never ever in your life use `gets`. My compiler even warns about using it whenever I try to (and I *don't*). Even the `man gets` page warns against it. C11 removed it. Just don't. Big no-no.

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: 0,1,2,3 **are** 4 inputs.

Comment: You can write it however fits your purpose. If you want the loop to loop 5 times it is more intuitive to write <5 rather than =<4, result is the same. Five iterations: with i =  0,1,2,3,4

Comment: 0,1,2,3,...,(n-1) are n input. counting? O.O

Comment: What are the `n-1` inputs you are providing? Maybe one of them is longer than 100 characters.

Comment: What about the newline left in the buffer by 'scanf("%d",&n);'?

Comment: @MartinJames u mean to say that newline buffer is getting into the loop for first iteration?

Comment: @tahsin yep, that's it. Just after the `gets(sr[i]);` do a `printf("X%sX\n", sr[i]);` and you'll see that the first input is an empty string

Comment: @IliaL yes thats what im saying. my code should looping n times but it is taking inputs n-1 times .after giving n-1 inputs it is showing the results n-1 times.

Comment: Golden rule: programmers start counting at 0, not 1 like normal people.  So if you ever see `<=` or `101` then you always want to look for a possible off-by-one bug.

Comment: @MartinJames thanks a lot. is it a good idea to use fgets to avoid this newline buffer getting into my loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `scanf("%d",&n);` executes, it consumes the numeral from the input but leaves the following character. This character is likely a newline character. Then, when `gets` executes, it reads this newline character. Thus, it puts this into `sr[0]` as a complete line—just a newline and no other characters. Your loop does not execute `n-1` times; it executes `n` times, but the first line is blank.

The easiest way to fix this is to change `scanf("%d",&n)` to `scanf("%d ",&n);`. The space after the `%d` tells `scanf` to consume white-space characters, which will remove the newline character from the input.

However, it will also remove spaces at the beginning of the next line. If you do not want that, leave the `scanf` as it is, but insert code to read (and ignore) characters until it reads a newline character.